# ChildWindow Modality

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, templating, childwindow

By default the ChildWindow Overlay covers (and disables) the entire root visual. I want to cover (and disable) just part of my UI. How can I alter the existing ChildWindow to allow me to specify the Root?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Out of interest, what were the edits?

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable only part of the underlying UI the whole of it is disabled. When the ChildWindow is active none of the controls on the underlying UI will receive Mouse or Keyboard events.

There is no way to limit the ChildWindow to a different Root, it is always rooted at the Silverlight control level.

Comment: Surely I could disable part of the UI by setting Enabled="False". If I could retemplate (or recreate) the ChildWindow and specify the root I could then disable this root?

Comment: @Mark: Just tweaked the answer a little to be clearer, the point is you can't disable __only__ part of the underlying UI, __all__ of it gets disabled when the Childwindow displays and there is nothing you can do to change that.